# Chrome Extension - Inject script at document-start and another at document-end on same content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this script that must be injected on document-start, before document.body exists (only head exists). This script hides some classes on the page via css styles before the body is created and add a centered div with a message after DOMContentLoaded, so the body exists. This script will not work if injected on document-body or document-end though :(

Besides this script I have another that will do some actions on the page, but that script needs document.body element, so it needs to be injected on document-end (document-body may work to).

Both scripts should run on the same content tab, one after the other.

#### The injection will be done on the background page, so how and where should I inject each script in the right place?

## cloak.js

---

```
// must be injected at document-start to work

function ShowMsg()
{
    // show message after body created
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.setAttribute( 'id', 'out_div_msg' );
    el.setAttribute( 'style',   'position:absolute; width:200px; height:100px; left:50%; top:50%;'+
                            ' visibility:hidden; z-index:999' );
    el.innerHTML =  '<div id="in_div_msg" style="position:relative; width: 100%;height:100%; left:-50%; top:-50%;'+
                ' visibility:visible; border:1px solid;"><table border="0" width="100%" id="table1" cellspacing="0"'+
                ' cellpadding="0" height="100%" style="border-style: outset; border-width: 2px; padding: 5px;'+
                ' background-color: #C0C0C0"><tr><td align="center" style="font-family: Consolas; font-size: 12px;'+
                ' color: #000000">Do not close this window<br><br>It will close automatically when finnished</td>'+
                '</tr></table></div>';
    document.body.appendChild( el );
}

// inject style before body created
var s = document.createElement('style');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
s.innerText = 
    ' .hot_news { display: none !important; }'+
    ' .bg-wall     { display: none !important; }'+
    ' .cmenu { display: none !important;' + 
    ' body { background-color: #000000; }';
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ShowMsg, false);
```

---

Thank you in advanced

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript

Answer (score 4):

Then why not split it into two separate content scripts?

### cloak1.js

```
// must be injected at document-start to work

// inject style before body created
var s = document.createElement('style');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
s.innerText = 
    ' .hot_news { display: none !important; }'+
    ' .bg-wall     { display: none !important; }'+
    ' .cmenu { display: none !important;' + 
    ' body { background-color: #000000; }';
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

### cloak2.js

```
// show message after body created
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.setAttribute( 'id', 'out_div_msg' );
el.setAttribute( 'style',   'position:absolute; width:200px; height:100px; left:50%; top:50%;'+
                        ' visibility:hidden; z-index:999' );
el.innerHTML =  '<div id="in_div_msg" style="position:relative; width: 100%;height:100%; left:-50%; top:-50%;'+
            ' visibility:visible; border:1px solid;"><table border="0" width="100%" id="table1" cellspacing="0"'+
            ' cellpadding="0" height="100%" style="border-style: outset; border-width: 2px; padding: 5px;'+
            ' background-color: #C0C0C0"><tr><td align="center" style="font-family: Consolas; font-size: 12px;'+
            ' color: #000000">Do not close this window<br><br>It will close automatically when finnished</td>'+
            '</tr></table></div>';
document.body.appendChild( el );
```

### manifest.json

```
{
    ...
    content_scripts: [
    {
        "matches": [...], 
        "js": ["cloak1.js"], 
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }, 
    {
        "matches": [...], 
        "js": ["cloak2.js"], 
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }, 
    ], 
    ...
}
```

And it seems that your first script is used to inject CSS. Therefore, you can also inject CSS directly using `"css": ["cloak.css"]` instead of `"js": ["cloak1.js"]`, where cloak.css contains those style declarations. CSS files are always injected "before any DOM is constructed or displayed for the page.", so you don't need the "run_at" field. 
For more information, see https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the code must be injected in the background. the code i pasted here is just one of the functionalities. the other code is different. But I got your point of view. @PAEz posted a comment that actually answered my question. I just cant accept it in a comment.